# Extract information from an XML file with help of XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I need data from the following XML file.
I need information where tag is `TYPE` and value is Version
for example `<TYPE index="1">Version 121212</TYPE>`
I can use XSLT and XPATH in my project.
Kindly help to get it done through XSLT or XPATH.

```
<CATALOG>
  <PLANT>
    <COMMON>Bloodroot</COMMON>
    <BOTANICAL>Sanguinaria canadensis</BOTANICAL>
    <TYPE index="1">Version 121212</TYPE>
    <TYPE index="2">Version2 121213</TYPE>
    <TYPE index="3">Version3 121233</TYPE>
    <TYPE index="4">Version4 121255</TYPE>
    <TYPE index="5">Version 121212</TYPE>
    <TYPE index="6">Version 121212</TYPE>
    <TYPE index="7">Version 121212</TYPE>
    <TYPE index="8">Version 121212</TYPE>
    <TYPE index="9">Version 121212</TYPE>
    <ZONE>4</ZONE>
  </PLANT>
</CATALOG>
```

Comment: Your question is not clear. There is no element named TYPE whose value is "Version". OTOH, **all** elements named TYPE contain the string "Version".

Answer (score 0):

> I need information where tag is TYPE and value [contains] Version

Try this XPath:

```
//TYPE[contains(text(),'Version')]
```

It selects all `TYPE` elements which text content contains "Version".

Answer (score 0):

As `XSLT`:

```html
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">
  <xsl:template match="TYPE">
    <h1><xsl:value-of select="."/></h1>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="//TYPE[contains(text(), 'Version')]" />
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```